# Tuning cloudera navigator

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-navigator

I'm trying to tune my Cloudera Navigator, the official documentation only gives recommendations about Cloudera Navigator metadata server memory sizing. Is there any complete documentation / post on Cloudera Navigator tuning?

thanks :)

Comment: What kind of tuning parameters you are looking for? Are you facing any problem with Navigator performance?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably referring to this.

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/admin_cn_admin.html

Navigator Audit Server - https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/cn_iu_audit_server.html

Navigator Metadata Server -
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/cn_iu_metadata_server.html

The Audit Server is controlled by the database you configure with it which is why there are no specific directions for tuning.  It all depends on which database you're using on the backend.